# Django: Applying indexes on abstract models so that children have it

Tags: django

Can we apply indexes on abstract models so that all children inherit it?

I have an abstract model which feeds other models :

```
from model_utils.models import UUIDModel
from django.db import models


class TimeStampedUUIDModel(UUIDModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class ModelA(TimeStampedUUIDModel):
    name_a = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class ModelB(ModelA):
    name_b = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

And I wanted to add an index on that abstract model so that I have :

```
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        indexes = (
            BrinIndex(fields=['created_at']),
            BrinIndex(fields=['updated_at']),
        )
```

I have this error:

```
(models.E016) 'indexes' refers to field 'created_at' which is not local to model 'ModelA'.
HINT: This issue may be caused by multi-table inheritance.
```

What is the best way to do [meta inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance) on such model ?

Comment: Curious, a `BrinIndex` makes sense for the `created_at` field, but why did you use it for the `updated_at` field as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each index must have a unique name; since children inherit the index name from the parent, a collision occurs, so an explicit name containing `'%(class)s'` must be set:

```py
class TimeStampedUUIDModel(UUIDModel):
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

   class Meta:
      abstract = True
      indexes = (
         BrinIndex(fields=['created_at'], name='%(class)s_created_at_index'),
         BrinIndex(fields=['updated_at'], name='%(class)s_updated_at_index')
      )
```

If other models inherit from `ModelA`, it should be set as abstract. Otherwise make them inherit from `TimeStampedUUIDModel` and redefine the common fields.